# Horizontal scrolling on a Div with BlackBerry Trackpad

Tags: blackberry

I have a HTML page with a horizontally scrolling div. The swipe gesture works perfectly on my device and I can scroll horizontally through my images. I however cannot scroll horizontally with the track-pad. I'm testing on a BB Bold. Could anyone please explain to me how I get this to work, if it is possible.

Sample:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12" style="overflow-x: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; white-space:nowrap; padding: 10px 0" x-blackberry-focusable="true">
<img src="toDeleteImages/1.jpg" height="100" style="display: inline-block" x-blackberry-   focusable="true" />
<img src="toDeleteImages/2.jpg" height="100" style="display: inline-block" x-blackberry-focusable="true" />
<img src="toDeleteImages/3.jpg" height="100" style="display: inline-block" x-blackberry-focusable="true" />
<img src="toDeleteImages/1.jpg" height="100" style="display: inline-block" x-blackberry-focusable="true" />
<img src="toDeleteImages/2.jpg" height="100" style="display: inline-block" x-blackberry-focusable="true" />
<img src="toDeleteImages/3.jpg" height="100" style="display: inline-block" x-blackberry-focusable="true" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add which development environment you using ?. java/qml/.... ?

Comment: Im using Webworks. So simple HTML and Javascript.